# For loop not initiated in method

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm very new to coding, so I was practicing with some simple stuff, and encountered a problem I've been trying to solve for about 2 hours now, and I have no idea what's even wrong with it.

The problem is that when I invoke either `crate.fillCrate();` or `crate.emptyCrate();`, nothing appears in the console, and when I invoke `crate.crateInfo();` the following appears in the console:

`A nice crate of Heineken
It contains 24 slots
slots:  are filled.
slots:  are empty.`

I guess this means my for-loops don't start, but I have no idea why...

My Main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Crate crate = new Crate(24, "Heineken");
    }
}
```

My Crate Class:

```
public class Crate {
    private int crateSize;
    private Bottle[] bottles = new Bottle[crateSize];
    public String brand = null;

    public Crate(int crateSize, String brand) {
        this.crateSize = crateSize;
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public void fillCrate(){
        for(int i = 0; i < bottles.length; i++) {
            if(bottles[i] == null && !bottles[i].getSpotInfo()) {
                bottles[i] = new Bottle(true);
                System.out.println("Spot " + (i+1) + " is filled.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Spot " + (i+1) + " was already full");
            }
        }
    }

    public void emptyCrate() {
        for(int i = 0; i < bottles.length; i++) {
            if(bottles[i] != null && bottles[i].getSpotInfo()) {
                bottles[i].makeSpotEmpty();
                System.out.println("Spot " + (i+1) + " is empty."); 
            } else {
                System.out.println("Spot " + (i+1) + " was already empty");
            }
        }
    }

    public void crateInfo() {
        System.out.println("A nice crate of " + brand);
        System.out.println("It contains " + crateSize + " slots");
        System.out.print("slots: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < bottles.length; i++) {
            if(bottles[i] != null && bottles[i].getSpotInfo()) {
                System.out.print((i+1));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(" are filled.");
        System.out.print("slots: ");
        for(int c = 0; c < bottles.length; c++) {
            if(bottles[c] != null && !bottles[c].getSpotInfo()) {
                System.out.print((c+1));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(" are empty.");
    }
}
```

And my Bottle class:

```
public class Bottle {
    private boolean occupiesSpot = false;

    public Bottle(boolean occupiesSpot) {
        this.occupiesSpot = occupiesSpot;
    }

    public void makeSpotEmpty() {
        occupiesSpot = false;       
    }

    public boolean getSpotInfo() {
        return occupiesSpot;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```java
    private int crateSize;
    private Bottle[] bottles = new Bottle[crateSize];
```

the bottles gets the size of 0 as crateSize is not initialized yet, you should instead do

```java
    public Crate(int crateSize, String brand) {
        this.crateSize = crateSize;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.bottles = new Bottle[crateSize];
    }
```

and also

```java
if (bottles[i] == null && bottles[i].getSpotInfo())
```

this line will cause a NullPointerException if the bottle is null, because you cannot call a method (getSpotInfo) on a null object. Thanks for @Turing85 for pointing this out as well.

Comment: One should mention that, after fixing this bug, the call to `fillCrate()` will result in a `NullPointerException`.